# Is there a way to run or trigger an existing DLP Job via Cloud Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-dlp

We're trying to find a way to trigger the job in the DLP via Cloud Composer.

We're using the google.cloud.dlp package (version 1.0.2) however, it's resulting to package issues. We're wondering if this can be done thru airflow operators (DLP related)

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance seen the example in apache airflow?

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dlp.py

does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/data_loss_prevention.html#jobs-job-triggers) for the creation and running of Cloud DLP job triggers. Also, you can check this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html) for provider package for `google` provider where your **Airflow version** must be from `3.0.0` to `3.8.0 below`.

If you are using `Python`, it is advisable to use `google.cloud.dlp_v2` as it is the **recommended Google client library** to access Cloud DLP. For `Java`, you can use `google-cloud-dlp` version `3.7.6`.